# Jgroup Clustering issue with TCP

Tags: jgroups, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using Hybris for eCommerce. Currently I'm facing a issue while maintaining the cluster when using Jgroup with TCP.
Below are the errors:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/09/26 11:18:57.505 | WARN  [OOB-221,hybris-broadcast,hybrisnode-01] [TCP] hybrisnode-01: no physical address for hybrisnode-02, dropping message

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/09/26 11:18:54.193 | WARN  [OOB-249,hybris-broadcast,hybrisnode-02] [TCP] hybrisnode-02: no physical address for hybrisnode-03, dropping message 

INFO   | jvm 3    | main    | 2014/09/26 11:18:51.058 | WARN  [OOB-657,hybris-broadcast,hybrisnode-03] [TCP] hybrisnode-03: no physical address for hybrisnode-04, dropping message
```

We stopped all the servers and restarted it to resolve the issue but were not sure about the root cause.

Can anyone suggest me the optimal way of configuration for `Jgroups` and `Hybris`.

Comment: What version are you using? There were bunch of issues related to dropping messages fixed around 3.5.0.Final (e.g. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JGRP-1814).

Comment: I'm using 3.2.5.Final version.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and `-Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=false` to the JVM configuration and that message will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JGroups UDP setup that ships with hybris.